# How do I download photos from Picasa to the iPod Photo Library for offline viewing?

Tags: ipod, picasa

I do not have Internet where I stay, so I want to download all of my photos in my Picasa album to my 32GB iPod for offline viewing.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a computer, download [Picasa 3.9 for Mac/PC](http://picasa.google.com) and use its batch downloading features. Then, in iTunes, connect your iPod, click Photos, check `Sync Photos from`:, and click the dropdown menu to reveal `Choose folder...` and navigate to `~/Pictures/Downloaded Albums/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/albumname/` (with xxxxxxxxxx being your Google user ID number and albumname being the album you wish to import to your iPod). Sync and finish!